# Difference between <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText> and <EditText>

Tags: android

I downloaded a code and the source is written in this format:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText/>
```

instead of:

```
<EditText/>
```

I tested both of them and i didn't see the difference, so I want to know if there's a difference between these two ways of declaring a widget in Android.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText/>
```

Creates a Field with an EditText with more functions like show the placeholder up the edit text when you're typing in.

https://gyazo.com/844d6c0fe8aace1ef671859823d39a58
https://gyazo.com/bf891de7807955e76bf487e3a07a6317

Comment: so, they're basically the same but <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText/> has more options? and you must choose the one who fills better your purpose at the moment?

Comment: You're describing `TextInputLayout`, not `TextInputEditText`. Also, please upload images here directly, by clicking [the image button above the edit box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRAP7.png).

Comment: Thnks Mike M. :) I'm new in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Only difference is: in landscape mode you can see the hint in `TextInputEditText1`, whereas you can't see in `EditText`.